# belongs_to reject if condition not meets in Rails 5 ActiveRecord Conditional Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, belongs-to

I have 2 models:

```
class PaymentRequest < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invoices, ->(request) { with_currency(request.amount_currency) }
end
```

and

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :payment_request, optional: true
  scope :with_currency, ->(currency) { where(amount_currency: currency) }
end
```

PaymentRequest may have only invoices of the same currency. And it meets the condition, while `payment_request.invoices` is called.

I have different currencies as following:

```
payment_request = PaymentRequest.create(id: 1, amount_currency: 'USD')
invoice = Invoice.create(amount_currency: 'GBP')
```

But, how to reject the following?

```
# no validation here
payment_request.invoices << invoice

# the payment_request_id is set to 1
invoice.payment_request_id #=> 1
```

One solution is adding the `has_many :invoices, before_add: :check_currency` and raise exception.

Is there a better solution to reject association?

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the following solution for currency validation:

```
class PaymentRequest < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invoices, ->(request) { with_currency(request.amount_currency) },
                      before_add: :validate_invoice

  monetize :amount_cents

  private

  def validate_invoice(invoice)
    raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid if invoice.amount_currency != amount_currency
  end
end
```